# Analytic continuations for $(-1)^x$ over the real number line

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, analytic-continuation

The function $f(x)=(-1)^x$ can only be mapped to the real numbers when $x\in\mathbb{N}$. So I wonder what analytic continuation can expand the domain of $f$ to all real numbers without changing the range from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{C}$. What continuous functions do this?

I found that $(-1)^x=\cos((2k+1)\pi x)$ when $x\in\mathbb{N},k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and the RHS is a function $\mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{R}$. Are there any others?

Comment: You can always add an arbitrary function which is zero at all integers, like $\sin(\pi x)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, $(-1)^x = e^{(i\pi + 2\pi i k)x}$ for any integer $k$. So if you just take the real part, $\cos((2k + 1)\pi x) $, you get a "standard" family of real valued functions that agree with $(-1)^x$ whenever $x$ is an integer.

Aside from that as others have commented, you can just add any function which zero at all integers, beyond that there is nothing more interesting to say about the question.

Comment: The general solution is to take $\cos((2k+1)\pi x) + g(x)$, where $g(x)$ is analytic and has zeros at every integer and $k$ is any integer.